# Emulate pipe with several outlets. Is python fast enough for this?

Tags: python, unix

I have input bytes from ffmpeg. I'd like to send this output to several other ffmpeg processes. Since I can't use a Unix Pipe, Socket,.. for this (or can I?) I'm using python as the receiving end of the pipe.
A subroutine then copies the received data to all previously "registered" outlets.

It feels wrong!

Specifically I have the feeling that this means a lot of memory copying. It works right now. But I'd seriously love to head about "the right way" of doing this.

```
    def writeData(self,data):
    """Write 'data' to all outputs"""
    if len(self.outlets) > 0:
        for outlet in self.outlets:
            outlet.writeData(data)
    else:
        self.logger.warn("Received data but no outlets registred (yet?)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely to be fast enough, especially with the speed of CPUs now compared to the relatively lower bandwidth of compressed video data.

As always, you will have to test and benchmark your solution to ensure that it meets your performance requirements.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: Thanks to Phil, who corrected an error in an earlier version (see the comments).

Using `bash`, you could do

```
ffmpeg ... | tee >(ffmpeg ...) >(ffmpeg ...) >(ffmepg ...) > /dev/null
```

This will pipe the output of the first `ffmpeg` to the three others.

If you don't use `bash`, you can manually create named pipes, connect them to `ffmpeg` processes and use `tee` to pipe to the named pipes:

```
mkfifo pipe1 pipe2
ffmpeg ... < pipe1
ffmpeg ... < pipe2
ffmpeg ... | tee pipe1 pipe2 | ffmpeg ...
rm pipe1 pipe2
```

The above `bash` code does basically the same.  The creation and removal of the named pipes happens transparently.

Comment: Tee is essentially doing the same thing as the python stuff above, right? I was wondering if the python way is significantly slower. I ask because I'd prefer python for flexibility.

Comment: @Thorsten:  I comply with Greg -- most probably, this won't be a bottleneck, but to be really sure, you will have to try yourself.  Since I/O is usually done in bigger chunks, I wouldn't expect Python to constitute much overhead.

Comment: Careful, this will pipe the output of the first, second and third ffmpegs into the fourth. A better pattern is "a | tee >(b) >(c) >(d) > /dev/null"

Comment: @Phil: Did you try it?  I tested my version, and it does not pipe all the outputs to the last process.  Not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: @Sven: `echo dog | tee >( grep d ) >( grep o ) | tr a-z A-Z` gives me all uppercase DOGs, suggesting the grep stdouts have been piped into tr. However `echo dog | tee >( grep d ) >( grep o ) >( tr a-z A-Z ) > /dev/null` doesn't mix the streams. The ordering of the shell processing that causes this is tricky; what was your test and output?

Comment: @Phil: Got my mistake.  My test was basically `echo dog | tee >(grep d) >(grep o) > some_file` to test what is going to stdout, but this is **not** the same as `echo dog | tee >(grep d) >(grep o) | cat > some_file`, which I wrongly assumed (I do understand why this is different now.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the "pee" utility from the moreutils package? It does just what you're describing:

`ffmpeg | pee 'ffmpeg -stuff1' 'ffmpeg -stuff2' 'ffmpeg -stuff3'`